# How do I replace the rownames of a data frame with information from another data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames `exp.kirp.log2` and `g_list` where the rownames of `exp.kirp.log2` matches the `g_list$hgnc_symbol`, but they are in **different orders**.
I want to replace the rownames of `exp.kirp.log2` with the `gene_list$ensembl_gene_id` based on the matching `g_list$hgnc_symbol`.

```
# Obtain g_list

genes <- rownames(exp.kirp.log2)
ensembl = useEnsembl(biomart = "genes", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", GRCh = 37, verbose = T)
ensembl <- useDataset(dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", mart = ensembl)
g_list <- getBM(attributes = c('ensembl_gene_id','hgnc_symbol'), 
                filters='hgnc_symbol',values=genes,
                mart=ensembl)
g_list <- g_list[order(g_list$hgnc_symbol),]

rownames(exp.kirp.log2) <- g_list$ensembl_gene_id %in% g_list[match(rownames(exp.kirp.log2), g_list$hgnc_symbol),2]
```

Traceback:

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length
```

`exp.kirp`

```
dput(exp.kirp.log2[1:20,1:20])
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A = c(7.65342121905285, 2.03892776611756, 
-0.96100202120249, 6.35598354101006, 14.3511850042327, -Inf, 
10.3737643425674, 3.79382306985866, -Inf, 10.0819596419255, 9.44832324553207, 
4.20886056913751, -0.96100202120249, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 5.36085937172008, 
9.78880184184623, 10.3776687573505, 11.16757118884), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A = c(5.09389393824392, 
5.2160706644244, -Inf, 6.93597002271109, 12.4136523086721, -Inf, 
11.1918237390263, 2.98724809259115, -Inf, 10.1912122382252, 9.9623840324273, 
4.71517403960983, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 6.22565668754941, 10.3398477765017, 
10.3103072842012, 11.1287210937383), TCGA.2Z.A9J2.01A = c(5.51854458067276, 
4.11644793551166, -Inf, 7.5307754013178, 12.2744679621487, -Inf, 
9.93114303849412, -Inf, -Inf, 10.3189198720956, 10.2574585613045, 
4.11644793551166, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 0.309059742501585, 6.16707286132018, 
10.2991951943744, 10.5852157015366, 11.5823040757623), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A = c(4.70168212029528, 
3.34111759260469, 3.57815377007565, 7.54694769203808, 10.1689338100564, 
-Inf, 9.96839262629172, 5.28865017271056, -Inf, 9.87305770150294, 
9.75535162798677, 3.57815377007565, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 6.170389794965, 
10.238532641469, 9.94050095178643, 11.0690397931313), TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A = c(7.99645936536463, 
5.20408983959317, 1.64952349150802, 6.89258167250936, 13.6832285748428, 
-Inf, 10.3714563849361, 2.6495004987031, -Inf, 10.4176870383992, 
10.0652444551968, 6.86867071663319, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -0.350522494468264, 
5.98935248863472, 10.1079093507719, 11.2050505161752, 11.6645692817891
), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A = c(5.13719199914349, 6.63590381796106, -1.00057719346275, 
6.92859654071157, 12.0367193976262, -Inf, 10.8202555636581, 5.50707469845262, 
-Inf, 10.3262700402849, 9.91216810777653, 5.94179415093086, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 5.52284042813955, 10.0653680664815, 10.5954686012028, 
11.2355920880251), TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A = c(6.95117512427229, 2.24944534108584, 
-Inf, 7.25014205824679, 10.9656928148969, 1.07949758402178, 10.5991523452113, 
4.32744306245973, -Inf, 10.4556415168452, 9.46537845450025, 3.66448284036468, 
-Inf, -Inf, -0.920570684997085, -Inf, 6.72337288854289, 10.0139441477751, 
9.28408724134641, 11.4833270722276), TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A = c(3.61712213221935, 
5.39472334226273, -Inf, 7.92111077839189, 11.9975977242282, -1.58251200148633, 
9.91379851626213, 5.10394657615628, -Inf, 9.95999222715916, 9.90779350021794, 
5.82683572660569, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 7.85831302551685, 10.3997246047534, 
11.7402171909708, 11.7246448152361), TCGA.2Z.A9J9.01A = c(6.05389548011115, 
-1.41888982477445, -Inf, 5.73237232300075, 14.8647326244225, 
-1.41888982477445, 10.4697437586612, 4.51174000542664, -0.419082711336792, 
9.28576885726015, 9.21399581402162, -1.41888982477445, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 6.0887945976893, 9.39798410008432, 9.51616568261168, 
11.1846268780251), TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A = c(3.15639661659767, 4.2623504664045, 
-Inf, 8.66937017282105, 10.9506421354115, -Inf, 10.8015070949819, 
1.37484474128973, -Inf, 9.51027580369917, 10.0114476969219, 4.30081927275683, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 5.9232585434528, 10.1410206692489, 10.9093204661635, 
11.1601119970792), TCGA.2Z.A9JE.01A = c(4.55671142771396, 0.976583597876997, 
-Inf, 7.39711669725343, 11.338916568945, 0.976583597876997, 11.4922670603536, 
2.97656526897918, -Inf, 10.098748119083, 9.84075338026455, 5.28034764124523, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 5.7709822912126, 10.6735346943631, 10.5435725361632, 
11.1417882886223), TCGA.2Z.A9JG.01A = c(7.27924748225939, 3.74051746156171, 
2.8145094080944, 5.79197812282256, 12.0865056775331, -Inf, 10.327056990394, 
3.53698537579194, -Inf, 10.5780583590704, 10.8649068477431, 6.57473428966518, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 7.25413670394464, 9.83577157545057, 10.6502486545903, 
11.1906393649786), TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A = c(8.20162111992077, 5.71548707501235, 
0.393526032228356, 5.73826794012289, 12.7954861179578, 2.61595767716595, 
10.0094938620897, 5.20091233325219, -Inf, 9.93400880935778, 9.75330735360058, 
5.21798676951157, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 7.0082672553098, 9.74081003982032, 
10.7382235152475, 11.6720072357516), TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A = c(6.26475409489153, 
-0.415229871442725, 4.46742296017359, 6.39123499553712, 12.8198023802381, 
-Inf, 11.7916439373724, 2.04421923663312, -Inf, 9.53606689182685, 
10.3591574288036, -1.41503749927884, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 
5.71406413888836, 10.0630462305102, 10.2195932783632, 11.455724780085
), TCGA.2Z.A9JK.01A = c(5.9386386584728, 6.15383572961508, -Inf, 
6.96731849612975, 14.0309071832818, -1.46076672913396, 10.1870344226096, 
1.99855658313033, -Inf, 9.35930526481309, 9.09945932891836, 4.68887411799513, 
1.99855658313033, -Inf, -Inf, -1.46076672913396, 6.2670469517503, 
9.44376099865969, 10.3192560726034, 11.2260646035167), TCGA.2Z.A9JL.01A = c(7.02541755196655, 
3.6235742674856, 0.623585972399712, 6.53709878587009, 12.9644083075158, 
-0.961282892427146, 11.008714051357, 7.39616034553605, -Inf, 
10.2035151452418, 9.55233575995403, 4.03861176676445, -Inf, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, 6.02729341208669, 10.2444014184424, 10.8539915160092, 
10.9360755463691), TCGA.2Z.A9JM.01A = c(5.91786850792426, 5.24907362097786, 
1.28557977040279, 6.72907414917957, 13.7490268867095, -Inf, 10.9548399985167, 
4.00806552147407, -Inf, 10.1222822552784, 9.55238706244896, 5.47146712618562, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -1.03622996892924, 6.23045858328003, 10.2600151849016, 
10.4635183450003, 10.7143794759862), TCGA.2Z.A9JN.01A = c(4.09355172548716, 
-Inf, -Inf, 7.28292161137752, 12.2911433534863, -Inf, 10.8165919471646, 
-1.22398025935253, -Inf, 8.92443634456794, 9.76180168782627, 
-1.22398025935253, -1.22398025935253, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 7.12910679128811, 
10.6459390192132, 10.9762453349304, 11.3740122319006), TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A = c(5.31084177712261, 
-0.707218250772154, 0.292663973396858, 7.23068817327933, 13.1978705809921, 
3.38016145559557, 9.83862580682156, -Inf, -Inf, 9.54417855835282, 
10.3479785104067, 5.93655314137344, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 6.95803180123955, 
10.5275135616911, 10.7557094705532, 11.5723066760841), TCGA.2Z.A9JP.01A = c(6.28494714327597, 
0.226878404196269, 1.22687840419627, 7.45773299323875, 13.34336295947, 
-Inf, 11.208058065601, 1.22687840419627, -Inf, 10.0414301364209, 
9.66875435596374, 4.51225217454896, -Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 0.226878404196269, 
6.145710058105, 9.94538047931203, 10.6250568350002, 11.0719455710567
)), row.names = c("A1BG", "A1CF", "A2BP1", "A2LD1", "A2M", "A2ML1", 
"A4GALT", "A4GNT", "AAA1", "AAAS", "AACS", "AACSL", "AADAC", 
"AADACL2", "AADACL3", "AADACL4", "AADAT", "AAGAB", "AAK1", "AAMP"
), class = "data.frame")
```

`g_list`

```
> dput(g_list[1:20,1:2])
structure(list(ensembl_gene_id = c("ENSG00000121410", "ENSG00000148584", 
"ENSG00000175899", "ENSG00000166535", "ENSG00000128274", "ENSG00000118017", 
"ENSG00000094914", "ENSG00000081760", "ENSG00000114771", "ENSG00000261846", 
"ENSG00000197953", "ENSG00000188984", "ENSG00000204518", "ENSG00000109576", 
"ENSG00000103591", "ENSG00000115977", "ENSG00000127837", "ENSG00000129673", 
"ENSG00000090861", "ENSG00000124608"), hgnc_symbol = c("A1BG", 
"A1CF", "A2M", "A2ML1", "A4GALT", "A4GNT", "AAAS", "AACS", "AADAC", 
"AADACL2", "AADACL2", "AADACL3", "AADACL4", "AADAT", "AAGAB", 
"AAK1", "AAMP", "AANAT", "AARS", "AARS2")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please show the genesis of `glist`? Did it derive from `exp.kirp.log2`?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Remove if no match

Comment: @Parfait I've updated the question with the genesis of `g_list`. It's derived from `exp.kirp.log2`

Answer (score 1):

1. Row names are discouraged if not actively removed by many functions in `dplyr` and the rest of the tidyverse. You would do well to either migrate them to a "real column" in the data or stop trying to use them (I suspect you need the information, so the former is your best path). In that regard, you can do

   ```r
   exp.kirp.log2 %>%
     tibble::rownames_to_column("hgnc_symbol") %>%
     right_join(g_list, ., by = "hgnc_symbol") %>%
     tibble()  # this is only "needed" to facilitate visualization here on Stack
   # # A tibble: 21 x 22
   #    ensembl_gene_id hgnc_symbol TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J2.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A
   #    <chr>           <chr>                  <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
   #  1 ENSG00000121410 A1BG                   7.65              5.09             5.52             4.70             8.00
   #  2 ENSG00000148584 A1CF                   2.04              5.22             4.12             3.34             5.20
   #  3 ENSG00000175899 A2M                   14.4              12.4             12.3             10.2             13.7 
   #  4 ENSG00000166535 A2ML1               -Inf              -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf   
   #  5 ENSG00000128274 A4GALT                10.4              11.2              9.93             9.97            10.4 
   #  6 ENSG00000118017 A4GNT                  3.79              2.99          -Inf                5.29             2.65
   #  7 ENSG00000094914 AAAS                  10.1              10.2             10.3              9.87            10.4 
   #  8 ENSG00000081760 AACS                   9.45              9.96            10.3              9.76            10.1 
   #  9 ENSG00000114771 AADAC                 -0.961          -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf   
   # 10 ENSG00000261846 AADACL2             -Inf              -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf   
   # # ... with 11 more rows, and 15 more variables: TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A <dbl>, TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A <dbl>, TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A <dbl>,
   # #   TCGA.2Z.A9J9.01A <dbl>, TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A <dbl>, TCGA.2Z.A9JE.01A <dbl>, TCGA.2Z.A9JG.01A <dbl>, TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A <dbl>,
   # #   TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A <dbl>, TCGA.2Z.A9JK.01A <dbl>, TCGA.2Z.A9JL.01A <dbl>, TCGA.2Z.A9JM.01A <dbl>, TCGA.2Z.A9JN.01A <dbl>,
   # #   TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A <dbl>, TCGA.2Z.A9JP.01A <dbl>
   ```

   FYI, my choice to use `right_join` was mostly for demonstration *here* on Stack, preferring to keep the two columns on the left side of the frame so they appear here in the truncated rendering. Normally, many people prefer the "thinking" of `%>% left_join(g_list, by = "hgnc_symbol")`, but the two calls are functionally identical other than the resulting order of columns.
2. If you really need them to be a row name, then you can always use the above, un-`tibble` the frame, then apply row names from `ensembl_gene_id`. Unfortunately, with your current data this cannot be demonstrated since you have duplicate symbols `AADACL2`, so row names will either fail or change the row names to force uniqueness, in which case some of your row names are not pristine.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `merge` on `row.names` and `hgnc_symbol`. Then, assign `row.names`  of `ensemble_gene_id` accordingly:

```r
exp.kirp.log2_new <- merge(
  exp.kirp.log2, g_list, by.x="row.names", by.y="hgnc_symbol"
)

rownames(exp.kirp.log2_new) <- exp.kirp.log2_new$ensembl_gene_id
colnames(exp.kirp.log2_new)[1] <- "genes"
exp.kirp.log2_new$ensembl_gene_id <- NULL
```

Output

```r
exp.kirp.log2_new

                  genes TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J2.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J9.01A TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A
ENSG00000121410    A1BG         7.653421         5.093894        5.5185446         4.701682        7.9964594         5.137192        6.9511751         3.617122         6.053895         3.156397
ENSG00000148584    A1CF         2.038928         5.216071        4.1164479         3.341118        5.2040898         6.635904        2.2494453         5.394723        -1.418890         4.262350
ENSG00000175899     A2M        14.351185        12.413652       12.2744680        10.168934       13.6832286        12.036719       10.9656928        11.997598        14.864733        10.950642
ENSG00000166535   A2ML1             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf        1.0794976        -1.582512        -1.418890             -Inf
ENSG00000128274  A4GALT        10.373764        11.191824        9.9311430         9.968393       10.3714564        10.820256       10.5991523         9.913799        10.469744        10.801507
ENSG00000118017   A4GNT         3.793823         2.987248             -Inf         5.288650        2.6495005         5.507075        4.3274431         5.103947         4.511740         1.374845
ENSG00000094914    AAAS        10.081960        10.191212       10.3189199         9.873058       10.4176870        10.326270       10.4556415         9.959992         9.285769         9.510276
ENSG00000081760    AACS         9.448323         9.962384       10.2574586         9.755352       10.0652445         9.912168        9.4653785         9.907794         9.213996        10.011448
ENSG00000114771   AADAC        -0.961002             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf
ENSG00000261846 AADACL2             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf
ENSG00000197953 AADACL2             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf
ENSG00000188984 AADACL3             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf       -0.9205707             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf
ENSG00000204518 AADACL4             -Inf             -Inf        0.3090597             -Inf       -0.3505225             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf
ENSG00000109576   AADAT         5.360859         6.225657        6.1670729         6.170390        5.9893525         5.522840        6.7233729         7.858313         6.088795         5.923259
ENSG00000103591   AAGAB         9.788802        10.339848       10.2991952        10.238533       10.1079094        10.065368       10.0139441        10.399725         9.397984        10.141021
ENSG00000115977    AAK1        10.377669        10.310307       10.5852157         9.940501       11.2050505        10.595469        9.2840872        11.740217         9.516166        10.909320
ENSG00000127837    AAMP        11.167571        11.128721       11.5823041        11.069040       11.6645693        11.235592       11.4833271        11.724645        11.184627        11.160112
                TCGA.2Z.A9JE.01A TCGA.2Z.A9JG.01A TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A TCGA.2Z.A9JK.01A TCGA.2Z.A9JL.01A TCGA.2Z.A9JM.01A TCGA.2Z.A9JN.01A TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A TCGA.2Z.A9JP.01A
ENSG00000121410        4.5567114         7.279247         8.201621        6.2647541         5.938639        7.0254176         5.917869         4.093552        5.3108418        6.2849471
ENSG00000148584        0.9765836         3.740517         5.715487       -0.4152299         6.153836        3.6235743         5.249074             -Inf       -0.7072183        0.2268784
ENSG00000175899       11.3389166        12.086506        12.795486       12.8198024        14.030907       12.9644083        13.749027        12.291143       13.1978706       13.3433630
ENSG00000166535        0.9765836             -Inf         2.615958             -Inf        -1.460767       -0.9612829             -Inf             -Inf        3.3801615             -Inf
ENSG00000128274       11.4922671        10.327057        10.009494       11.7916439        10.187034       11.0087141        10.954840        10.816592        9.8386258       11.2080581
ENSG00000118017        2.9765653         3.536985         5.200912        2.0442192         1.998557        7.3961603         4.008066        -1.223980             -Inf        1.2268784
ENSG00000094914       10.0987481        10.578058         9.934009        9.5360669         9.359305       10.2035151        10.122282         8.924436        9.5441786       10.0414301
ENSG00000081760        9.8407534        10.864907         9.753307       10.3591574         9.099459        9.5523358         9.552387         9.761802       10.3479785        9.6687544
ENSG00000114771             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf         1.998557             -Inf             -Inf        -1.223980             -Inf             -Inf
ENSG00000261846             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf
ENSG00000197953             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf
ENSG00000188984             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf
ENSG00000204518             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf             -Inf        -1.460767             -Inf        -1.036230             -Inf             -Inf        0.2268784
ENSG00000109576        5.7709823         7.254137         7.008267        5.7140641         6.267047        6.0272934         6.230459         7.129107        6.9580318        6.1457101
ENSG00000103591       10.6735347         9.835772         9.740810       10.0630462         9.443761       10.2444014        10.260015        10.645939       10.5275136        9.9453805
ENSG00000115977       10.5435725        10.650249        10.738224       10.2195933        10.319256       10.8539915        10.463518        10.976245       10.7557095       10.6250568
ENSG00000127837       11.1417883        11.190639        11.672007       11.4557248        11.226065       10.9360755        10.714379        11.374012       11.5723067       11.0719456
```